# Platform Developer 2 Exam

Tags: certification, platform-developer-2

As we all know that instead of having to complete a Assignment we will have to complete the Super Badges (Salesforce Recommended ones) to get PD2 certified which I have completed along with multiple choice online exam. After finishing my online exam I got an email from Salesforce asking me to link my Trailhead Account and Webassessor which I did.

How long does it take before I get the certification completion acknowledgement from Salesforce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It takes approximately one week. They issue the certification regularly, but it is not instantaneous.

From the Knowledge article [Link Your Trailhead and Webassessor Accounts](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Link-Your-Trailhead-and-Webassessor-Accounts):

> Step 4 - Salesforce grants you the credential: We will monitor your progress and when requirements have been completed, we will update your credential status within 1 week and an email confirmation will be sent to you. For Platform Developer II, once the credential is granted, your email confirmation will include your certificate and logo, and your credential will display on the verification site (if you have opted in).

Answer (score 2):

Certification does not monitor Stack Exchange. I would suggest opening a case at certification.salesforce.com.